# How to implement ngIf in td

Tags: angular

I have a table where I insert data from DB, however, I want to edit those data which are qualified based on my checking and therefore should be 2 buttons, 1 for delete and 1 for the edit which would be enabled. If the row inserted in the table is not qualified I want to disable those buttons. What is the right implementation of this scenario?

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of reservations">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{item.numberOfGuests}}</td>
    <td>{{item.timetables}}</td>
    <td>{{item.data}}</td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="{{item.data}} => today && {{item.data}} <= tomorrow"> <a>Ala bala</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

A few things to say: item.data is of type date as MM-dd-YYYY and so is today which is the date of today and so is tomorrow which is the date of tomorrow.

Edit: 
Posting the error:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 12 in [item.data 
> => today && item.data <= tomorrow] in 
> ng:///AppModule/ReservationtableComponent.html@72:33 ("             <td> 
> {{item.data}}</td>
>                       <td>
>                         <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="item.data => today && item.data 
> <= tomorrow"> <a>Ala bala</a></div>
>                       "): 
> ng:///AppModule/ReservationtableComponent.html@72:33
> at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016)
> at 
> TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler. 
>  js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14813)
> at 
> JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler 
> .js.JitCompiler. _parseTemplate (compiler.js:23992)
> at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js. 
> JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:23979)
> at compiler.js:23922
> at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at 
> JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler. 
> js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23922)
> at compiler.js:23832
> at Object.then (compiler.js:1007)
> at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler. 
> js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23831)
> ```

Comment: I think you do not need to add double curly bracket. do your condition checking without `{{}}`.

Comment: @GabrielCostin ``*ngIf="item.data >=  today && item.data <= tomorrow">`` try this

Comment: @GabrielCostin it should not be `=>`, it should be `<=`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Still get a template parse error, will edit my post and will post error

Comment: Post exact error message

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Thanks for help, the reason was  somehow I typed => instead of >= and didn't checked it later:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the interpolation brackets in angular-parts (like ngIf).

```
<div *ngIf="item.data >= today && item.data <= tomorrow"
```

And you can put *ngIf into td as well as in any other element (html, angular-component).

Answer (score 0):

First thing no need of interpolation binding in *ngIf.
Inside  you can create a button with only one disabled property. Like

```
<td>
   <button [disabled]="item.editable"> Edit </button>
</td>
```

Same for delete button as well.

You can set the editable and deletable property in component by checking the rules you want.

I think this would be an easy and clear implementation.

Answer (score 0):

use `*ngIf="item.data >= today && item.data <= tomorrow"` and  remove `{{ }}` from ngIf

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of reservations">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{item.numberOfGuests}}</td>
    <td>{{item.timetables}}</td>
    <td>{{item.data}}</td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="item.data >= today && item.data <= tomorrow"> 
          <a>Ala bala</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```